# How can I reference a html element position in respect to another element's position in CSS?

Tags: css, reference, position

Say I have 2 html elements, in different parts of a html form: element "first-element" and element "second-element".

"first-element" is a flex item, which varies in position with page resize (the flex wraps).
When I hover the first element, I would like to make "second-element" visible and position it 20px down from "first-element".

I tried:

```
#first-element:hover #second-element {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:#first-element.left;
    height:#first-element.top+20px;
}
```

which, obviously didn't work :)

Can you please tell me if such a thing is possible and what is the correct syntax? Or, maybe suggest another approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need jQuery or Javascript to do this. It is not possible with only CSS.

See an example here with jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function{

$('#first-element').hover(function(){
   $('#second-element').toggle(200);
})

})
```

Style the rest of what you want in your css.

```css
#second-element{
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
}
```